# Member variable with template non-type arguments without templating class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, member, non-type

I am trying to implement a class which will have a linear_congruential_engine member. I don't want to force an implementation, but I'm not sure that's possible because linear_congruential_engine is implemented as a template with non-type arguments.

Example of what I am trying to acheive:

```
template <class T> MyClass {
protected:
    template<T a, T c, T m>
    std::linear_congruential_engine<T, a, c, m> randEngine;
public:
    template<T a, T c, T m>
    MyClass(std::linear_congruential_engine<T, a, c, m> randEngine) {
        this->randEngine = randEngine;
    }
}
```

Allowing:

```
int main() {
    MyClass<uint32_t> ex1(std::minstd_rand0());
    MyClass<uint32_t> ex2(std::minstd_rand());
}
```

Is this possible? My gut says no, but hoping somebody more familiar with templates could tell me otherwise or suggest a clever workaround.

Comment: Workaround: write your own engine.

Comment: instantiations with different template arguments would be treated as different types. so I guess maybe you can introduce a type-erasured base level with a typed (via tepmlate) level for specific usages. This is somewhat like how `shared_ptr` stores its deleter.

Comment: If all you really need to do is to construct MyClass with no template parameters, just make your class `template <class T, T a, T c, T m> class MyClass` and use the constructor like this: `MyClass x{std::minstd_rand0()};`. If you need two classes, which have members parametrized with different values, to have the same type, I don't think that's possible.